# How to configure SpamAssassin to set Atlassian JIRA notifigations to white list?

Tags: spamassassin, spam-filter, jira

I have problem Atlassian JIRA email notifications. These notifications come to deleted by SpamAssassin some reason.

So I need to know how to confirgure SpamAssassin to but these notications to whitelist.

I configured xxx@i4ware.fi email to whitelist but that does not help or I just confirgured this wrong.

I tested now my JIRA and all emails that is sent from address xxx@mydomain.com to xxx@mydomain.com is deleted with SpamAssassin and emails that is sent from yyy@mydomain.com to xxx@mydomain.com come to not deleted with SpamAssassin. This occurs only JIRA but not other Atlassian products like FishEye or Crucible, etc.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Here is smtp result:

```
root@alm:~# postconf | grep smtpd_recipient_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter:    virtual_overquota_bounce=yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter:    virtual_maildir_limit_message="The user you are trying to reach is over quota."
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_override=yes
```

Comment: What are the SA logs for these mails?

Comment: Where do I can find SA Logs on Ubutnu 14.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.

[create a rule](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/WritingRules)

```
header LOCAL_JIRA From =~ /example\.com/i
score LOCAL_JIRA  -100
```

Where example.com is your specific instance name, you can also do full emails like

```
header LOCAL_JIRA From =~ /jira-emailer\@example\.com/i
```

For Postfix whitelist, follow [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-whitelist-hosts-ip-addresses-in-postfix)

Comment: I tested this now and this does not help!

Comment: Can you post your header results? what is the email system (MTA)

Comment: header LOCAL_JIRA From =~ /alm\@i4ware\.fi/i
score LOCAL_JIRA  -100

allow_user_rules on

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-ubuntu-14.04-lts

Comment: what are the results of postconf | grep smtpd_recipient_restrictions

Comment: I added these to my original question.

Comment: Did you run spamassassin --lint

Comment: No.. I try if it helps

Comment: spamassassin --lint did not help.

Comment: I tested now my JIRA and all emails that is sent from address xxx@mydomain.com to xxx@mydomain.com is deleted with SpamAssassin and emails that is sent from yyy@mydomain.com to xxx@mydomain.com come to not deleted with SpamAssassin. This occurs only JIRA but not other Atlassian products like FishEye or Crucible, etc.

Comment: full headers or get a consultant.